# Merge two Maps into a sequence scala

Tags: scala

I have two Maps like below

```
Map("x" -> Seq("abc"), "z" -> Seq("ghj")) and Map("y" -> Seq("xyz"), "z" -> Seq("pqr"))
```

The output I want is to combine these two maps into a single sequence such that keys present in both Maps should have two non empty sequences while keys present in only one of the Maps should get the corresponding Seq and an empty Seq.

```
Seq(("x", Seq("abc"), Seq()), ("y", Seq(), Seq("xyz")), ("z", Seq("ghj"), Seq("pqr"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
val result = (m1.keySet ++ m2.keySet).map {
  k: String => (k, m1.getOrElse(k, Seq()), m2.getOrElse(k, Seq()))
}
```

Comment: Concise and easy to understand. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my ugly solution.

```
val res1 = map1.map { case (k, v) => if (map2.contains(k)) (k, v, map2(k)) else (k, v, Seq()) }
val res2 = map2.filter { case (k, _) => !map1.contains(k) }.map { case (k, v) => (k, Seq(), v) }
val res3 = res1 ++ res2
res3.toList.sortBy(_._1)
```